# App-Linking in Android, assetlinks.json, IIS, can not get it work

Tags: android, json, xamarin, iis

I have followed this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking

First I created a Digital Asset File **.well-known/assetlinks.json** stored in my IIS server.
I can see it is downloadable by running:
https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=%20http://(MY_WEBSITE):&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls
And no errors found, good.
I can access the .json file by just navigate to that file via a webbrowser.

This is configured in the Web.config in IIS

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
```

The assetlinks.json (generated from the Statement List Generator and Tester) looks like this

```
[
   {
      "relation":[
         "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target":{
         "namespace":"android_app",
         "package_name":"com.p******.***************",
         "sha256_cert_fingerprints":[
            "31:2E:AC:5B:16:5C:82:A4:9A:6A:63:6B:86:94:64:70:CA:4D:72:2E:28:3F:43:3F:27:4B:2D:18:AB:BD:3F:35"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

I got the SHA 256 cert from the Google Play Developer Console in the App-signing page of my uploaded app (as closed test-app).

But when I test it from this site: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator then I get this message **"No app deep linking permission found for  at (Hosting site domain)"**

Is there something I have missed?

Some tests, first says error:
[image]

Second test with the google api, says no errors.
[image]

Last test I can see the app is listed:
[image]

Comment: Did you follow this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking#testing-app-links

Comment: Yes, The first test says "Errors: None!", second test open the browser in the device and just open my homepage without menu for choosing my app. Third test says that the app is listed and points to the correct Domain with status "Ask".

Comment: Can you try to use a different Android device?

Comment: I found the problem... I will post the answer soon.

Comment: Yes please post the answer, I m curious to know too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now.

The wrong I did was by mistake add the "http://" DataScheme to the DataHost in the IntentFilter attribute in MainActivity class.
[image]

I juste removed it and everything works, now it looks like this when I run the command to see my app listed:

[image]

(Command: adb shell dumpsys package domain-preferred-apps)